# Python: Compare a field in a list with a blacklist field

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I want to compare the rows in a spreadsheet (CSV) with a list[] of good values, and create a blacklist of the bad rows (any row that contains a value that doesn't appear in the whitelist is printed to a file).

```
if any(item in row[4] for item in lisst):
    print(rowEdit) #scaffolding
    writer.writerow(rowEdit)
```

matches everything to the items in the whitelist and writes it to file

```
if any(item in row[4] for item not in lisst):
    print(rowEdit)
    writer.writerow(rowEdit)
```

seems like it ought to print me the part of the file that is not whitelisted, for manual edit to add to the whitelist.  It doesn't.

The data I am sorting is a CSV file with asset-data.  I want to output split by OS, which is the row[4] list item.
The indentation is a little messed up...

```
    import csv

def main():
choice = "chew"
filename=raw_input("enter the filename==>  ")
while choice != "swallow":

    os_choice = raw_input('Enter  "1" for Linux,\n       "2" for Windows\n       "3" for all others and\n       "4" to exit the script =>  ')

    qu = ""
    if os_choice == "1":
        qu = "nix"
    elif os_choice == "2":
        qu = "win"
    elif os_choice == "3":
        qu = "other"
    elif os_choice == "4":
        choice = "swallow"
        break
    else: continue
    #t=titleblock(filename)
    #L=labels(filename)
    c=content(filename, qu)

#   print(t,'\n',c,'\n',r,'\n')
return 0

def content(filename, qu):

with open(qu+'_content_'+filename, 'wb') as content:
    writer = csv.writer(content)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as mycsv:
        reader = csv.reader(mycsv)
        counter = 0

        for counter,row in enumerate(reader):
            if counter < 7: continue
#               if counter > ([-2:]) : break # This string-slicing technique doesn't work on lists made by csv module for some reason
            rowEdit = [row[0],row[22],row[2], row[4], row[6], row[15], row[16], row[11], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[28], row[29], row[30], row[31]]
            chklist=["OS", "Linux 2.4-2.6 / Embedded Device", "Linux 2.4-2.6", "Linux 2.6", "Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES 4", "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.8", "Linux*"]
            chklist2 = "Linux"
            wchklist=["OS", "Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2", "Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit Edition Service Pack 1","Windows"]
            ochklist=chklist+wchklist
            if qu == "nix":
                lisst = chklist
                if any(item in row[4] for item in lisst):
                    #print(rowEdit)
                    writer.writerow(rowEdit)
            elif qu == "win":
                lisst = wchklist
                if any(item in row[4] for item in lisst):
                    #print(rowEdit)
                    writer.writerow(rowEdit)
            elif qu == "other": 
                lisst = ochklist
                splisst = set(lisst)
                #if any(item not in row[4] for item in lisst):
                if splisst & row[4].split():
                    print(rowEdit)
                    writer.writerow(rowEdit)
```

In the end - was hunting for type() that made it clear to me - as usual, I was trying too hard.

```
elif qu == "other": 
lisst = ochklist
if row[4] not in lisst:
    #print("eureka")
    #print(rowEdit)
    writer.writerow(rowEdit)
```

Thanks for helping me work through it.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the test with the loop; move `not` to the `in` test expression in the generator expression:

```
if any(item not in row[4] for item in lisst):
```

The `for item lisst` part loops over `lisst` elements, and the first part of the generator expression is the actual test.

Depending on how `row[4]` is structured, it may be more performant to make your whitelist a set:

```
whitelist = set(lisst)

if whitelist.intersection(row[4].split()):
    # True if any whitespace separated value in `row[4]` is a member of whitelist too
```

Comment: That runs smoothly, but produces a file with all 23 rows.  Should only come up with a file with 1 item specifically made to not be in lisst

Comment: @WolfHalton: Without more sample details about the contents of `lisst` and `row[4]` it is impossible to tell what goes wrong for you. Could you add some to your question?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test061.py", line 88, in <module>
    main()
  File "test061.py", line 47, in main
    c=content(filename, qu)
  File "test061.py", line 83, in content
    if splist & row[4].split():
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'

Comment: The working (or broken) code is at https://github.com/wolf29/csv-edit/blob/master/test061.py

Comment: Python 2.5 and earlier require the second argument to be a set too: `splist & set(row[4].split())`

Comment: oh - sorry, this is python 2.7.3

Comment: @WolfHalton: Indeed; it seems that even on 2.7.3 the `&` operand still needs to have a set rh operand as well; the `.intersection()` method does the same thing, what works correctly. You really want to move `chklist`, `wchklist` and `ochklist` declarations *out* of the loop (they are constant anyway) and create that set *once*, not for every loop iteration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31140/discussion-between-wolf-halton-and-martijn-pieters)